# Closed-form expression for the value of $\underset{\|x\|_1 = 1}{\min }r\|x\|_2 + a^\top x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, noneuclidean-geometry

Let $a$ be a fixed vector in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $r \ge 0$.

> **Question.** Is there a closed-form expression for the value of $\underset{\|x\|_1 = 1}{\min }r\|x\|_2 + a^\top x$ ?